# How do I create metal frames with crossbars having the same circular crosssections?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have been trying to create metal frames using cubes, both using the wireframe modifier and trying to generate thickness by changing edges into curves and creating thickness. I have found that if the vertices of the edges have more than two edges connected that the thickness of the generated wireframe OR edges are not uniformly thick through their lengths. I have not changed the size of the starting faces or edges from the default. Is there an easy technique that allows me to create crossbraces for my frames allowing for a consistent crosssection of the component pieces?

[image]

Comment: please post screen shots of current results and sketches of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: we can't undestand what you mean if you don't provide screenshots or a .blend file